# Проблема с Parse push-уведомлениями Swift iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Я подключил все frameworks как расписано на офиц. сайте Parse, ошибок в коде нет, даже вылезает alert с вопросом разрешить push уведомления, но при публикации уведомия с Parse сайта статус положительный (галочка) , написанно даже, что новый пользователь зарегистрирован, а в уведомлении отправлено (Pushes sent) всегда написано 0 , и уведомления не вылезают ? Вот так выглядит мой код :

```
//AppDelegate
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    Parse.setApplicationId("zMeZbr9sfYSeRqqLONcjbDcL6lpXWXWROSoVDEKX",
        clientKey: "Whotpga5dCDY96bpfYiHHl8MNEQGJcLhGagfFWkA")

    // Register for Push Notitications
    if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
        // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
        // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
        // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.

        let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
        let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
        var pushPayload = false
        if let options = launchOptions {
            pushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil
        }
        if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || pushPayload) {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
        }
    }

        let types: UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


    return true
}


func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    if error.code == 3010 {
        print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")
    } else {
        print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы на реальном устройстве проверяете или на симуляторе?

Comment: на реальном устройстве

Comment: push me baby попробуйте запустить, там все просто, нужно будет один раз deviceToken (из метода делегата вытащите его) свой туда прописать, и попробуйте пушить